# Launching a 3rd party application restarts it instead of resuming

Tags: android, launcher

Just for learning purpose, I am making a shortcut launcher like application. Purpose is  simple; in my application, user picks some preferable apps, and taps one of them to launch it.

After searching for proper `FLAGS` to be used for an `intent` while launching an application, this is my code:

```
 Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName);
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

 if (i != null) startActivity(i);
```

While this works fine for some applications, it acts weird for others.

The problem is, for some applications, if the application is already running; instead of resuming to its previous state it restarts its main activity, as if it was never used. Examples are Android's default *Messaging* app, *Settings* application.

And for others, it restarts for the first time and then starts resuming. 
For applications like *Whatsapp*, *Adobe Reader*.

There are no such problems when launching applications from other launchers.

---

I have been searching through the entire internet since last two days, and tried a whole lot of solutions from different blogs and from hundreds of similar questions asked in SO itself, but none worked. I've even looked through the code of default *Android launcher*, which BTW launches the applications perfectly,
but found no success.

I know this is a super duplicate question, but I am only asking because none of the solutions that I've tried worked for me. Thanks for helping.

---

### Edit

In case it has anything to do with the manifest, here it is,

```
  ...  
  <activity
        android:name=".SwitchActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_switch"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
  ...
```

Comment: What happens if you simply use the `Intent` returned by `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` without modifying it?

Comment: @Karakuri Then all applications are restated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the lines in between like this

```
 Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName);

 if (switchIntent != null) startActivity(i);
```

The problem is probably caused by the following line

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
```

Moreover, it is not needed to `setAction` and `addCategory` as well, as those should be done by `getLaunchIntentForPackage` already.

Edit:

You may use Activity Manager to get Running Tasks and resume them.

**However**, `getRunningTasks` is disabled starting on Lollipop.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

> This method was deprecated in API level 21. As of LOLLIPOP, this
>   method is no longer available to third party applications: the
>   introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person
>   information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still
>   retu rn a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks,
>   and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be
>   sensitive.

Comment: Removed the lines as you said, but still no success :(

Comment: does it at least fix the problem of this? `And for others, it restarts for the first time and then starts resuming. For applications like Whatsapp, Adobe Reader.`

Comment: Yes yes it does, just checked it. This problem is fixed but the other one still exists.

Comment: Actually `getLaunchIntentForPackage` is equivalent to opening the application in Launcher, or the Home Screen you may call. So for some application, it could be designed in a way that it is not "resuming" if you open it from Launcher.

Comment: Oo, but what do other launchers add to it to resume those applications perfectly?

Comment: if you are talking about the switch task button on android, I believe it is handled by system application by not Launcher, I have edited to add one more alternative, however, `getRunningTasks` has been disabled since Lollipop

Comment: No no, even the launchers resume those applications even in Lollipop. Dunno how :(

Comment: Are you sure it is "Launchers"? Which Launcher? Maybe I can take a look and learn something too.

Comment: The default launcher seems to do somehow, but I will try that on my friend's phone with lollipop using other launchers  and get back in touch later. Thanks.

Comment: Just tell me that there aren't a whole bunch of such applications not made to be resumed.

Comment: Not working at all bro, not in Lollipop. All apps are being restarted.